# What will happen to the program if they have no braces?

Tags: c++

```
if(a>=6)
{cout<<"out of range"; return 0;}
```

If this program did not have a brace, what will happen to the program?

Answer (score 5):

Will only return if `a >= 6`:

```
if(a>=6)
{
  cout<<"out of range";
  return 0;
}
```

Will return regardless of the value of `a`:

```
if(a>=6)
  cout<<"out of range";
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the above lines are the entire program, aka the body of main, there is no difference in between the version with and without braces. Not explicitly returning a value from main is equivalent to returning 0.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of braces (`{}`),depending on value of `a`, you will get out put of printed on `out of range`. But, it is guaranteed to `return 0;`, since it doesn't come under if condition.